# Hive data transformations in real time?

Tags: hive, apache-kafka, hdfs, dashboard, spark-structured-streaming

I have the following data pipeline:

1. A process writes messages to Kafka
2. A Spark structured streaming application is listening for new Kafka messages and writes them as they are to HDFS
3. A batch Hive job runs on a hourly basis and reads the newly ingested messages from HDFS and via some medium complex INSERT INTO statements populates some tables (I do not have materialized views available). **EDIT**: Essentially after my Hive job I have as result *Table1* storing the raw data, then another table *Table2 = fun1(Table1)*, then *Table3 = fun2(Table2)*, then *Table4 = join(Table2, Table3)*, etc. *Fun* is a selection or an aggregation.
4. A Tableau dashboard visualizes the data I wrote.

As you can see, step 3 makes my pipeline not real time. 
What can you suggest me in order to make my pipeline fully real time? **EDIT**: I'd like to have Table1, ... TableN updated on real time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using Hive with Spark Streaming is not recommended at all. Since the purpose of Spark streaming is to have low latency. Hive introduces the highest latency possible (OLAP) since at backend it executes MR/Tez job (depends on hive.execution.engine).

**Recommendation:** Use spark streaming with the low latency DB like HBASE, Phoenix.

**Solution:**  Develop a Spark streaming job with Kafka as a source and use the custom sink to write the data into Hbase/Phoenix.

Comment: Thanks. However where should I do my data transformations (table1, ... tableN)?  Directly in Spark and write each result to a different table? What I thought was having kind of materialized views that would update themselves realtime... But maybe I am totally wrong.

Comment: Why Spark Streaming? That's deprecated for Structured Streaming. And Kafka Connect exists as well

Comment: Data transformations should be done in Spark using SQL/functional transformations. It's really fast because of lazy, in-memory computations and optimized query plans.  

Spark - DStreams is deprecated. Spark Streaming/Structured streaming is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Introducing HDFS obviously isn't real time. MemSQL or Druid/Imply offer much more real time ingestion from Kafka

You need historical data to perform roll ups and aggregations. Tableau may cache datasets, but it doesn't store persistently itself. You therefore need *some storage*, and you've chosen to use HDFS rather than a database.

Note: Hive / Presto can read directly from Kafka. Therefore you don't really even need Spark.

If you want to do rolling aggregates from Kafka and make it queryable, KSQL could be used instead, or you can write your own Kafka Streams solution

Comment: Would you really use Kafka for storing your data history? :S